# Assigning a vector to a single element

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

Consider `std::vector<T>` for some type `T`. I receive a pointer to such a type into a function, and also an instance of `T`; `t` say.

My function looks like this:

```
void bar(std::vector<T>* foo, const T& t)
{
    foo->clear();
    foo->push_back(t);
}
```

Is there a way I write the function body in one statement? `*foo = t;` does not work due to an appropriate assignment operator not existing. I was also thinking of using

```
foo->assign(&t, &t + 1);
```

but that seems naughty.

I'm using C++11.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can reassign:

```
*foo = {t};
```

Comment: The assign version is probably better has it may reuse the memory of the previous vector instead of reallocating one tho.

Comment: For reference, the `= {t}` syntax only works in C++11 and later. For earlier versions, you could use `*foo = vector<T>(1, t);` instead, but `foo->assign(1, t)` is better.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason you can't just use `std::vector<>`'s **other** `assign()` member function?

```
void bar(std::vector<T>* foo, const T& t)
{
    foo->assign(1, t);
}
```